# How to get values from git repo in spring config server/client

Tags: java, spring-boot, github, config, spring-cloud-config-server

Below is my application.property file

`codes:"{alpha:'green',bravo:'red'}"`

my config class looks likes below,

```
@Configuration  
@ConfigurationProperties
@RefreshScope
public class ConfigFile {

????

}
```

My Question is how can I set my git repo values using ConfigurationProperties class ?
Note: Using @Value is not recommended

Thanks in advance.

Comment: it's as simple as having the `.properties` file inside your project resources. Just use `@Value` annotation with an attribute like `@Value("${codes:}") private String codes;`. for more info https://spring.io/guides/gs/centralized-configuration/

Comment: I have to use @ConfigurationProperties(prefix= "user") instead of @value

Comment: I would suggest you to read up on `@value` and `@configurationproperties`. I believe you are mixing up two things

Comment: in that case rename the property in `.properties` file to `user.codes` as you wanna use `prefix= "user"` and just declare an attribute called `private String codes;` here is my resource  https://www.baeldung.com/configuration-properties-in-spring-boot#simple-properties

Comment: I have corrected my code